# Copy command using variables in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cp

I am doing something like this

```
backEnd_root=`cat "$user_data_file" | grep "backEnd_root"|cut -d ":" -f2`
backEndStatic=`echo "$backEnd_root/ui/static"`
echo "Destination is $backEndStatic"
```

Value of $backEnd_root is: /Users/naresh.joshi01/Documents/Projects/Process_Management/BackEnd_Branches/develop/peloton

Result of echo command is like this:

Destination is /Users/naresh.joshi01/Documents/Projects/Process_Management/BackEnd_Branches/develop/peloton
/Users/naresh.joshi01/Documents/Projects/Process_Management/BackEnd_Branches/develop/peloton/ui/static

Why does it show two values for the same variable?

Comment: Add an echo statement after the first line and check whether the grep and cut is giving the right value for backEnd_root.

Comment: No idea why but it seems to be working fine now without any changes

Comment: Don't use backticks. Use the modern syntax `$(grep ...)`. Don't use cat, if it is [useless](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Don't use `echo` in a sub shell, if you just assign one variable to another.

Comment: @NareshJoshi : Please update the title of your post to something more meaningful. There is no copy command in it.

Comment: `backEnd_root=$(awk '/backEnd_root/{print $2}' FS=: "$user_data_file")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that your variable `backEnd_root` does not have the value you think. Most likely, `backEnd_root` occurs twice in $user_data_file. What happens if you replace the first line by

```
backEnd_root=$(grep backEnd_root "$user_data_file"|cut -d ":" -f2|head -n 1)
echo backEnd_root=$backEnd_root
```

?